# Dataweave 1.0 ( Mule 3 ) contains not returning expected results while checking payload

Tags: mule, dataweave

So I will receive a post request with a JSON payload.
I need to check if the payload contains the keyword `Moscow` anywhere in the payload ( not a specific attribute or field )

Sample payload :

```
{
   "city": "Paris",
   "zip": "123",
   "street" : "some street name"
}
```

I dont want to check for individual attributes of the payload as this check for `Moscow` would need to be applied for other endpoints having different payload format as well ...

So I am converting input payload to a String:

```
<object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to string" />
```

and then I am using a transform  component as :

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform">
<dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
  payload contains "Moscow"
}
```

when I run in debug mode and evaluate , if payload contains "Moscow" anywhere it says True but when the actual code runs it is always returning false ? ( tried doing a exact match so that upper / lower case would not cause an impact )

Not sure what I am missing ?

edit1 :
complete script as below :

```
<byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
         %output application/json
         %var result1 = payload contains "Moscow"
         %var result2 = payload.city contains "Moscow"
         ---
         {
            "isMoscow" : payload contains "Moscow",
             "isMoscow" : result1 as :string,
             "isMoscow" : result2 

          }]]></dw:set-payload>

          </dw:transform-message>
```

so now even if I send payload as :

```
{
   "city": "Moscow",
   "zip": "123",
   "street" : "some street name"
}
```

Result is :

```
{
"isMoscow": false,
"isMoscow": "false",
"isMoscow": true
}
```

Notice that it is only true when I am explicitly comparing `payload.city` and false when I compare directly against payload

Comment: What is the input string to the DataWeave transformation?

Comment: Are you sure that's the right script? Looks not to be valid

Comment: have updated with complete details thanks

Answer (score 2):

The results are correct, for the input payload that you shared. The fact that `payload.city contains "Moscow"` returns `true` means that the payload is an object, not a string. So it follows that the `contains` operator will not return `true` for the payload, since it is only expected to work on arrays or strings. Probably DataWeave understand that the payload is a string containing a JSON object and parses it as an object.

Because the input is a JSON string then you can use the expression `write(payload,"application/json")` instead of the `payload`, so it is truly a string.

As for the object to string transformation you should check if it is redundant since it appears to not achieve the expected outcome and a pure DataWeave approach could replace it.

Comment: Thanks @aled , however converting using ```write(payload,"application/json") ``` and then checking still returns false ...

Comment: You need to check what really is the payload before the DataWeave operation because that should not happen. What exact version of Mule 3 are you using? Did you removed all other transformers? What is the class and content in the debugger?